# Windsor Facility Error

Tags: wcf, castle-windsor, ioc-container, facilities, wcffacility

Everytime I try to add a facility to my Windsor container instance, I see the following exception:

```
Derived method 'Dispose' in type 'Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.WcfFacility' from assembly 'Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration, Version=2.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc' cannot reduce access.
```

This has happened for both the AutoTx facility, and the WCF facility.

Looking in reflector, the Dispose method in this class is protected, and is also protected in the class from which it inherits.

My project references the same versions of Castle.Windsor and Castle.Core that the WcfFacility demo references.

Any ideas?

I've scoured the web for answers, by no luck.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a versioning issue! My project was referencing an out of date Castle.Windsor.dll